# How to put 9X equally sized buttons over a ImageView in Constraint Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have a ImageView inside a Constraint Layout as follow

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/argentina"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
```

and i want to cover this image with a 9X equally sized buttons as shown Here[image: Problem Describing Image]

notice that the Imageview change with the size of the constraint layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can achieve that using **constraint** **chain** and the **match_constraint(0dp)** property
you have to define here **vertical** **and** **horizontal** **chain** to all button below is the sample for same

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/firefox"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button41"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button31"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button311"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button51"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button133"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />




        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button311"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button31"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button13"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button133"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button133"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button311"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button41"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button51" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button133" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button51"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button41"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button311"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button51" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button51"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button11"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button133"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the **design** and **blue print**
[image: design and blue print]

you can get all the details here about chain and constraint 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains

this will work on all device size and orientation

**NOTE:** i recommend u too add some minHeight to your image view so to avoid to hiding the button but i don't know your requirement but it an noticeable point

Comment: Thanks a lot this is what i was searching for one more question: Is there any way to Eliminate the Gaps (Vertical and Horizontal) between the Buttons !!

Comment: spacing is by default, same also for linear layout too, but when u set the button background it will cover gap with button background, i have question if you covering imageview here then why u using that in background.

Comment: The buttons are to be invisible later on !!